# What's are some good routers to use with OpenWrt, Tomato or the like?

Tags: wifi, router

I have an Asus RT-AC68U using DD-WRT that is showing its age.

Or rather, I have given up tracking down DD-WRT builds for it and would like to use another open source router OS on my next router.

#### Criteria:

- low power consumption, which probably rules out x86-based pfSense
- a sane website to find new builds that work for that model.  Maybe from the manufacturer?
- a router OS with a **currently** active community and development, based on Linux or BSD
- less than $400 (probably ruling out pfSense again).
- ideally, capability to install something like pi-hole directly on the router's DNS stack.

I don't mind paying some money to get this right, especially on the OS side of things.